# Magento In Subdirectory, Cookies being cleared

Tags: magento-1.9, cookie

I've got Magento installed in the sub-directory `/shop/` and whenever I go to the root directory my cookies get cleared and the basket is empty.

I believe this is because I've got the Cookie Path set to `/shop/`, but if I remove that or set it to `/` then I can no longer login to the admin area.

Any ideas? Running Magento 1.9.3.2.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the subdirectory as a subdomain?

I use a subdirectory for my staging area and the path is still /, but your cookie domain must be the FQDN that you use to view the site (www.WEBSITE.com) or (shop.WEBSITE.com) etc..

My exact settings are:
Cookie Lifetime - 86400
Cookie Path - /
Cookie Domain - staging.WEBSITE.com
Use HTTP Only - No
Secure on Frontend - Yes
Cookie Restriction Mode - No

Your site may need different settings depending on your use of SSL or multistore setup.